# Ruby On Rails with HTML5 and CSS3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, html, css

Does Ruby On Rails automatically use HTML5 and CSS3? If not how do I put them in my Ruby On Rails website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as far as i know you dont "put" html5 and CSS3 anywhere...

they are just newer features available along with the existing html4 and css...
Meaning if you use some new html5 feature as long as the client's browser supports it you have no worries...

like say you use a video tag in your html, if the user has a proper browser (say the newer versions of firefox and chrome) it will work... nothing to configure n your server.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to get started with [Guide to HTML5 Boilerplate for Rails Developers](http://railsapps.github.com/rails-html5-boilerplate.html)

Answer (score 1):

By writing HTML and CSS.

HTML5 and CSS3 are just a set of relatively new features.
You can use them wherever you want.

Comment: so they are already there? Because html5 requires a certain doctype.

Comment: you write your own doctypes in each view, rails may come with one default but just write whichever one you want to use in a layout

Comment: @user1233418: They can't *already* be there. You have to write them in order for them to be there. And what does the HTML5 doctype have to do with Rails?

Comment: @user1233418: HTML5 does not _require_ a certain doctype; it just recommends a simpler one.  And the built-in Rails template already uses that, IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

Rails uses the same version as you write. So when in your layout is HTML5, Rails generate HTML5.

I would suggest an interest in [compass](http://compass-style.org), if you want use CSS3.